# Getting timestamp of ERC721 token minting

Tags: erc-721, events, timestamp

what is the correct approach to find minting time of a token?

- External services like alchemy do not provide the info
- fetching events via ethersjs or similar does not provide block/timestamp info

Answer (score 0):

You can check the transfer receipt event log in the transaction receipts of ERC721 NFT tokens where you can see the initial mint from the 0x0 address to a target address/contract. Then you can trace the transaction to its corresponding block number that has a timestamp.

Comment: It's the second part i'm missing "trace the transaction" : the event has only from,to,tokenId